# Automatic email with specific excel files attached not being sending with NO ERROR - python

Tags: python, sql-server, email-attachments

I have some automation codes for report emails for awhile. One of those codes had worked fine for about 3 months, but suddenly it stoped being sent. When checking the code, everything works fine and the script return no error. It finishes with sucess but the email don't arrive at the mail inbox.

Those reports are made of SqlServer queries that are read with pandas and saved as excel files and then attached to the email and sent. The queries are working on Azure Data Studio (it is not sql error), are read ok by pandas and the dataframes are shown as expected, the excel files are being saved with the expected content.

The strange fact is that if I build a new query using other database and do the same thing, using the same program, the same directory, it works! And it works if I add new files at the attachment of new queries (it is not a problem in the attach code), but if I add a file of those specific queries then it stop hitting the inbox mail, but with no error throwed.

The program worked fine for 3 months and just stopped. The emails are not being sent to the spam folder either. The files are about 900KB, so it's not their size either, since I have other reports much larger.

Here are part of the code with one of those queries that doesn't work (very simple, only simple joins):

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from datetime import date
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import time
import glob

query_final_goal = '''
SELECT 
    pdvg.name AS 'REDE',
    pd.registrationNumber AS 'CNPJ', 
    p.name AS 'participant_VENDEDOR',
    u.name AS 'user_VENDEDOR', 
    u.username AS 'CPF',
    u.email AS 'EMAIL',
    CASE WHEN u.status=1 THEN 'ATIVO' 
        WHEN u.status=2 THEN 'INATIVO' 
        WHEN u.status=3 THEN 'PRECADASTRO'
        WHEN u.status=4 THEN 'PENDENTE'
        WHEN u.status=5 THEN 'REPROVADO'
        ELSE CAST(u.status AS VARCHAR) END AS 'STATUS',
    uc.finalgoal AS 'META_FINAL',
    uc.reference AS 'REFERENCIA'
FROM goalclassification uc
INNER JOIN [user] u ON u.id = uc.userId
INNER JOIN participant p ON p.id = u.participantId 
INNER JOIN pdvgroup pdvg ON pdvg.id = p.pdvGroupId
INNER JOIN pdv pd ON pd.pdvGroupId = pdvg.id
ORDER BY pdvg.name, uc.reference
'''

# Reading query
df_final_goal = pd.read_sql_query(query_final_goal, conn)

# Saving excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter(f'./report_final_goal-{year}-{month}-{day}.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') as fp:
    df_final_goal.to_excel(fp, index=False)

### SAME PROCESS FOR MORE 5 QUERIES



# sending email with multiple files
time.sleep(5)

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
mail_from = 'username@email.com'
mail_to = 'receiver@email.com'
mail_subject = f'Report {day}/{month}/{year}'
mail_body = f'Here are the reports of {day}/{month}/{year}'
mail_attachment = [f'./report_final_goal-{year}-{month}-{day}.xlsx',
                   f'./other-reports-{year}-{month}-{day}.xlsx']
                   

mimemsg = MIMEMultipart()
mimemsg['From'] = mail_from
mimemsg['To'] = mail_to
mimemsg['Subject'] = mail_subject
mimemsg.attach(MIMEText(mail_body))

for file in mail_attachment:
    with open(file, 'rb') as attachment:
        mimefile = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        mimefile.set_payload(attachment.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(mimefile)
        mimefile.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = f'{file}')
        mimemsg.attach(mimefile)


mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('xxxxxxxxx', 587)
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.starttls()
mailserver.login(username, password)
mailserver.send_message(mimemsg)
mailserver.quit()

time.sleep(5)
```

Does any one know what could be happening? Is it a bug of a new update of SQLServer or python packages? Shouldn't I receive and error for some reason?

It doesn't make any sense for me anymore.

Comment: SMTP should not be considered to be a reliable message delivery service. Any mail server along the delivery route can silently drop a message into /dev/null due to spam/UCE control policies. You don't seem to be doing any DKIM/DMARC setup on your messages. Does your SQL Server's public IP address appear in your domain's SPF (Sender Policy Framework) TXT record in DNS?